# JInja2 Template Syntax Error Encountered Unknown tag 'endif'

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I am building a basic api based website as I was going to display some info om page and was checking for a condition i encountered --
**jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endif'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.**
Below is the palatte I copied form Bootstrap and was modifying and then the error happened -- And Yeah This is my first time posting question here as you can tell!

```html
{% include "header.html" %} 
{% block contnet %}

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-dark">
    <div class="col px-2 py-5">
      <h6 class="px-2 py-3">Click to Know Upcoming Events</h6>
      <a href="{{ url_for('upcoming_events') }}"
        ><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mx-2 my-3">Events</button></a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <table class="table table-borderless py-5 table-light">
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-light">
            <th scope="col">Batting</th>
            <th scope="col">Bowling</th>
            <th scope="col">Wickets</th>
            <th scope="col">Over</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% if error %} # <========
              <p>{{ error }}</p>
            {% endif %}  <======= Here is the error traceback
     
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"></th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          {% endif %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You close the "if" twice (`{% endif %}`) but only open one...
Try this:

```
Click to Know Upcoming Events Events Batting Bowling Wickets Over

{% if error: %}
    {{ error }}
{% endif %}
    Mark Otto @mdo 2 Jacob Thornton @fat 3 Larry the Bird @twitter
{% endblock %}
```

You can move the `{% endif %}` where you want